# I want to make command for my discord bot so it can answer an embed

Tags: discord.js, command, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot for my own server. I'm new at coding so I don't have idea of anything.

Basically what I want to do is type in a specific channel for example '`!hello`' and my bot answer an embed to that '`command`'.

I hope someone can help me.

I'm trying to use this basic code but I can't do that bot answers an embed.

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  
  if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "boss")) {}
```

Thanks ;).

Comment: I am not sure how much you understand, so please paste the complete code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FUGTiWLP

Comment: what is your `discord.js` version?

Comment: @DarshanB last version

Comment: @TekIcyOP I've answered your question.

Comment: @TeklycyOP i can't see your pastebin (Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using discord.js **v14**, here's an example of how to respond to a command with an embed:

```js
// your client, prefix, etc. should already be configured
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "boss")) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("Hello!");
        message.reply({
            embeds: [embed]
        });
        return;
    }
})
```

Read more in the [discord.js docs](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/).

References: [EmbedBuilder](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/EmbedBuilder)